# JavaScript canvas generic drawImage

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawimage

I have been using drawImage to cause some video to explode as taught in this tutorial:
http://www.craftymind.com/factory/html5video/CanvasVideo.html

I would like to also be able to manipulate other objects using drawImage. The thing is when I try this on anything other than an image/video (an Iframe for example), I get a type error.

- Is there some way around this?
- Is there a way to get the "pixels" of an arbitrary control on my html5 page?

Comment: when you say "other objects", are you referring to objects other than those on your canvas?

Comment: Yes, I have been able to use video and img tags as input for graphics on the canvas. These objects were on the same document, but had nothing to do with the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, you can't. Canvas is a pixel manipulated sandbox. Other elements on a webpage are rather like vector graphics, you can only manipulate their certain attributes like: width, height, color, position, etc.

But this is considered a good thing. Imagine how much extra work it would mean to render a single page, if everything could be manipulated pixel-by-pixel. Also consider that hardware acceleration is a rather new area, and that websites should run on devices with different computational capabilities.

Even though the hypertext web has gone a long way to become an interactive application platform, yet the technological boundaries are still limiting some areas of competition with visual/performance features of a native app.